# Join table on already joined table

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'm struggling to put together a select statement that joins 3 tables.

Here's the database:

```
CREATE TABLE Beerstyles
(
  style_id     INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  style_name   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Breweries
(
  brew_id   INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  booth_num VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  brew_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Beers
(
  beer_id      INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  beer_name    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  alc_vol      DECIMAL(2,1) NOT NULL,
  fk_style_id  INT NOT NULL,
  fk_brew_id   INT NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Favorites
(
  fav_id      INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id     VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
  fk_beer_id  INT NOT NULL,
  fav_comment VARCHAR(255)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


ALTER TABLE Beers ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BeerStyle_Style FOREIGN KEY (fk_style_id) REFERENCES    Beerstyles (style_id);
ALTER TABLE Beers ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BeerBrew_Brew FOREIGN KEY (fk_brew_id) REFERENCES Breweries (brew_id);
ALTER TABLE Favorites ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FavBeer_Beer FOREIGN KEY (fk_beer_id) REFERENCES Beers (beer_id);
```

And here's the first part:

```
SELECT * FROM Favorites JOIN Beers ON Favorites.fk_beer_id = Beers.beer_id
```

I need to mix in the brew_name, but haven't been able to get it right. When I try to join Breweries (ON Favorites.fk_brew_id = Breweries.brew_id) i get an error saying "Unknown column 'Favorites.fk_brew_id' in 'on clause'"

Hope you guys can help me out :)

Comment: Your `Favorites` column is `fk_beer_id`, not `fk_brew_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Favorites 
JOIN Beers 
   ON Favorites.fk_beer_id = Beers.beer_id
JOIN Breweries 
   ON Beers.fk_brew_id = Breweries.brew_id
```

Of course is real life you shoudl never use select *. When you have a join you are repeating columns and causing your query to be slower.

Comment: Thanks!
I made a change to avoid the 'SELECT *':

    SELECT user_id, beer_name, alc_vol, brew_name, style_name FROM
    (SELECT * 
    FROM Favorites 
    JOIN Beers 
       ON Favorites.fk_beer_id = Beers.beer_id
    JOIN Breweries 
       ON Beers.fk_brew_id = Breweries.brew_id
    JOIN Beerstyles
       ON Beers.fk_style_id = Beerstyles.style_id   
       ) a
I still don't get how the letter at the end makes it work..

Answer (score 3):

There is no `fk_brew_id` in the `Favorite` table, but you have to add the `JOIN` condition to the `Beers` table not to the `Favorite` table like this:

```
SELECT 
  bw.brew_name,
  b.beer_name,
  f.fav_comment,
  ...
FROM Favorites       AS f
INNER JOIN Beers     AS b  ON f.fk_beer_id = b.beer_id
INNER JOIN Breweries AS bw ON b.fk_brew_id = bw.brew_id;
```